# How to change remote PostgreSQL connection's editor(PSQL_EDITOR)?

Tags: postgresql-9.3

I've added `PSQL_EDITOR` on my own PC(windows) and the remote PC(ubuntu14), it works fine when I try to use `\e` in psql, but when I connect the remote PC that doesn't work any more.